# a singe video on its own does not appear on screen when using jquery slider

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an application here where I am using jwplayer in basic jquery slider: [APPLICATION](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text3.php)

Info for basic jquery slider here: http://basic-slider.com/

Now this is what I have found out, if a slider contains multiple videos, then it displays the slider, but if a slider has one video only, it does not display video or slider.

Now what is strange is if I replace the videos for images, then it works if I have a single image as it does not display the slider but displays the image, this is fine. But my question is how to do the same thing for the video?

Here is demo for slider with images: [APPLICATION](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text20.php)

Below is code for video and slider:

```
     $vidquery = "SELECT s.SessionId, q.QuestionId, v.VideoId, VideoFile
                FROM Session s
                INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
                INNER JOIN Video_Question vq ON q.QuestionId = vq.QuestionId
                INNER JOIN Video v ON vq.VideoId = v.VideoId
                WHERE s.SessionId = ?";

    $vidqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($vidquery);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $vidqrystmt->bind_param("i",$session);
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $vidqrystmt->execute(); 
    $vidqrystmt->bind_result($vidSessionId,$vidQuestionId,$vidVideoId,$vidVideoFile);

        $arrVideoFile = array();

    while ($vidqrystmt->fetch()) {
    $arrVideoFile[ $vidQuestionId ][] = basename($vidVideoFile);
  }

    $vidqrystmt->close(); 


?>
<form action='results.php' method='post' id='exam'>


<?php
                //start:procedure video
        $vid_result = '';
        if(empty($arrVideoFile[$key])){
          $vid_result = '&nbsp;';
        }else{

            ?>


 <div id="banner-video_<?php echo $key; ?>">
 <ul class="bjqs">
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($arrVideoFile[$key] as $v) { ?>
<li><div id="myElement-<?php echo $key.'-'.$i; ?>">Loading the player...

<script type="text/javascript">


jwplayer("myElement-<?php echo $key.'-'.$i; ?>").setup({
    file: "<?php echo 'VideoFiles/'.$v; ?>",
    width: 480,
    height: 270
});

<?php $i++; ?>
</script>

</div>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>

         <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

         $('#banner-video_<?php echo $key; ?>').bjqs({
            animtype      : 'slide',
            height        : 300,
            width         : 700,
            responsive    : true,
            randomstart   : false,
            automatic : false
          });  
          });

          </script>

<?php

        }
        //end:procedure video
?>

</div>



</form>
```

UPDATE:

If anyone knows how to code it so that if it is able to detect if single video, then do not place it in slider, then I believe this could solve it.

Comment: Do you initialize $arrVideoFile as an array before it's populated? like: `$arrVideoFile=array();`  Does the script produce any errors?

Comment: @starshine531 Sorry did not see your comment, The script does not have any errors and I do have `$arrVideoFile=array()`, I updated code to show this

Comment: This doesn't exactly solve your issue, but why not just detect if it is one object and not put it in a slider?

Comment: @Goddard if you know how to code this then I will be very happy doing it this way and really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am saying is that by your example it looks like all your slider does it slide a image or video over and display the next or previous, but if you have only one item why not just skip all that entirely.

You have an array : `$arrVideoFile`

You can use `count($arrVideoFile);` to get the total values in the array.

So

```
if(count($arrVideoFile) != 0 || $arrVideoFile) != 1)
{
    //do the stuff you pasted above
}

else
{
    //if(array == 0) maybe show a default image

    //if(array == 1) lets just show that
        //if image show <img> if video show <object> or in your case 
        //<div id="myElement-<?php echo $key.'-0'; ?>"></div>
}
```

Let me know if this helps